# Toad windows explorer

Tags: windows, toad

When I want to Open or Save a file in Toad, the Windows explorer opens as:

[image]

So that I have to click all the way through the desired folder. I'd rather have it open as:

[image]

Such that I can just paste the whole folder path. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the folder path in the Filename edit and it will navigate.